# Why does the algorithm not accept float numbers?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

**Task**:
There are two teachers. They give grades for a student's work. There's a final grade. It is equal to the teacher's grade if they give the same grade. Or the final grade is -1 if the teachers have made different grades. 
I want to teach the computer to see this logic.

**Data**:

1. Rate1 - First teacher assessment
2. Rate2 - Second teacher assessment
3. Result - Final evaluation

**Example**:

0,1; 0,1 => 0,1

0,7; 0,7 => 0,7

0,3; 0,2 => -1

My code:

```
import pandas
MyData = pandas.read_excel("train.xlsx")
input_data = MyData.drop("Result", axis=1)
target = MyData.Result
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
model = RandomForestClassifier()
model.fit(input_data, target)
```

And after that, I get the next mistake. If all my estimates are integers, this error is absent. But I have to work with fractions.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-433a918946a9> in <module>
----> 1 model.fit(input_data, target)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_forest.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    319         self.n_outputs_ = y.shape[1]
    320 
--> 321         y, expanded_class_weight = self._validate_y_class_weight(y)
    322 
    323         if getattr(y, "dtype", None) != DOUBLE or not y.flags.contiguous:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_forest.py in _validate_y_class_weight(self, y)
    539 
    540     def _validate_y_class_weight(self, y):
--> 541         check_classification_targets(y)
    542 
    543         y = np.copy(y)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py in check_classification_targets(y)
    167     if y_type not in ['binary', 'multiclass', 'multiclass-multioutput',
    168                       'multilabel-indicator', 'multilabel-sequences']:
--> 169         raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
    170 
    171 

ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'
```

p.s. My data is [here](https://send.firefox.com/download/18e0b9c298ed95ad/#wPTUyMSzGo1pzs-BdM3e_A).

**How can I work with fractional numbers?**

Comment: please try to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and help us to help you

Comment: did you read the link I posted? Please take some time to read it will help you. About your question [I think this will help](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/fractions.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating large fractions in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50140323/calculating-large-fractions-in-python)

Comment: there are many other questions/answers on SO about fractions in Python [try taking a look](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Python+fractions)

Comment: Do you need machine learning for a simple rule like that?

Comment: Yes, I need.My task is described at the beginning of my post.

Comment: I did read the task. This does not require machine learning at all, the way you describe it.

Comment: Of course it's not necessary, but I want to follow this example. It'll help me start to understand a little bit how it works. I want to do more difficult things with this example. I need to solve this problem with ML.

Comment: My two cents: you will *not* be able to solve this with ML, as it is way more difficult (in a subtle way) than you seem to realize. Resolving the coding error will not actually get you any closer to solving the problem, and the only thing it may help you understand is the *limitations* of ML.

Comment: @MathiasMüller Exactly because it is *not* arithmetics; it needs a higher-order logic to "realize" what it means for the two input features to be equal, which is not available in ML models.

Comment: @MathiasMüller it is, with ultra-complex models, intermediate representations (embeddings), and tons of data; not with an RF-like model in what seems to be OP's *introduction* to the subject of ML. In any case, setting up some dummy data to resemble OP's problem, shouldn't be that hard, so we could see. And again, these NLP/MT models are usually hopelessly *bad* in capturing higher level semantics (and no one is surprised, actually).

Comment: @MathiasMüller thanks; although the 2 results you show look good, I rerun it and they now seem to [suck](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1p9k9_Ar7VR0nRbCK-LStMDQShrPveKRP?usp=sharing) (well, the inequality ones at least). Keep also in mind that you have created 10K training samples of what is actually a very *confined* sample space (i.e. numbers from 0.1 to 0.9), which gives a very high probability many of the samples we try to have already been in the training set. Anyway, not the right place to continue the discussion, but thanks for challenging me and insisting on it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass float values to a classifier. Try instead with Decision Tree Regressor, where you can pass integer values.

Here is an example code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'train.csv')

X = df.iloc[:, :1].values
y = df.iloc[:, 2].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor 

DTR = DecisionTreeRegressor()

DTR.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215063/discussion-on-answer-by-vincent-r-panahi-why-does-the-algorithm-not-accept-floa).